# Auto-Value-Gson : Cannot resolve symbol GsonTypeAdapter

Tags: auto-value

I have so far implemented a `Parcelable` class with `AutoValue` and now I'd like to be able to deserialize it `Gson`.

So I have found the `AutoValue` Extension named [auto-value-gson](https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson) and I have tried to implement a class just like the examples on the github page.

So my class changed to :

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class UploadPhotoResponse implements Parcelable{
    public abstract String getError();
    public abstract UploadPhotoResponseNestedItem getPost();

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new AutoValue_UploadPhotoResponse.Builder();
    }

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public static abstract class Builder {
       public abstract Builder setError(String error);
       public abstract Builder setPost(UploadPhotoResponseNestedItem post);

       public abstract UploadPhotoResponse build();
    }

// This is the new code I have added 
   public static TypeAdapter<UploadPhotoResponse> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {      
        return new AutoValue_UploadPhotoResponse.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }

}
```

but I'm getting error : "Cannot resolve symbol `GsonTypeAdapter`"

I'm using the following dependencies (just in case something is missing) :

```
provided 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.3'
apt 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.3'
apt 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.5'
apt 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.4.5'
provided 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.4.5'
annotationProcessor 'com.gabrielittner.auto.value:auto-value-with:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Do you get different errors before for `AutoValue_UploadPhotoResponse`. If you try to clean the project.

Comment: Clean project did the job!

Comment: In case anyone else is struggling, in my case my IDE auto imported a different `TypeAdapter` and thus faced this problem even after having the static method mentioned in the document. It worked once I ensured the correct import i.e. `import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter`